# If $α,β,γ$ belong to ${1,w,w^2}$ then how is number of triplets satisfying $|(aα+bβ+cγ)/(aβ+bγ+cα)| = 1$ equal to $9$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

My book gives this question, where $1$, $w$ and $w^2$ are cube roots of unity. In the solution given it is written that there are 9 ways in total, when  $α,β,γ$ are different (6 cases) and when they are the same (3 cases). Now I understood the three cases when $α=β=γ=1$,$w$ or $w^2$, but how do I find the 6 cases when $α,β,γ$ are different? Also, what about the cases when 2 of them are same while the third is different (eg. $α=w,β=1,γ=1$)? How do I tackle this problem?

Comment: Are $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ complex Numbers? If so, are $a,b,c$ real numbers?

Comment: $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are given to be in the set of cube roots of unity.

Comment: Okay thanks for pointing that out, but what about $a,b,c$?

Comment: He ought to say: I guess real

Comment: It is actually not mentioned what a,b,c are bu I think they are real.

Comment: "the same" and "different".  Does "the same" mean at least two the same or does it mean all three are the same.  Does "different" mean at least one is not equal to another or does it mean all three are distinct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work out although it is a rather brute force method. Assuming $A,b,c\in R$$$$$
Hint 1: $\left|\dfrac{a\alpha+b\beta+c\gamma}{\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\alpha\gamma}\right|=1\Rightarrow |a\alpha+b\beta+c\gamma|=|\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\alpha\gamma|$

Hint 2: $|z|^2=z\bar z$ Hence, $(a\alpha+b\beta+c\gamma)(a\bar\alpha+b\bar\beta+c\bar\gamma)=(\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\alpha\gamma)(\bar\alpha\bar\beta+\bar\beta\bar\gamma+\bar\alpha\bar\gamma)$

Hint 3: On expanding you will get terms involving $|\alpha|^2,|\beta|^2,|\gamma|^2$. These are each respectively equal to $1$, since $|1|=|\omega|=|\omega^2|=1$.

Note: I would have posted this as a comment, but it was too long for a comment.

Comment: Why is |w| and |w^2| = 1? Aren't they cube roots of one?

Comment: "Aren't they cube roots of one? "  Yes, and what is the absolute value of a cube root of one?

Comment: @Hema See [here](http://www.math-only-math.com/the-cube-roots-of-unity.html)

Comment: On calculating we get |w| = |w^2| = 1, since for instance w = -1/2 + i root3/2 . I got it, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Another way would be to simply evaluate the roots of unity in Polar form.

Comment: But how is the no. 9 of triplets , can't understand...